# How do I remotely copy a mongo database with authentication?

Tags: mongodb, copy, remote-server

I'm trying to copy an existing mongo database "test" on a remote server to the same remote server but it should get a different name "test2". 
Mongodb is password protected on this server.

Is there any easy way to do this? ( I want to create a shell script out of this)

What I tried is to connect to mongo by using

```
mongo "IP"
```

Then I tried to use the db copy

```
db.copyDatabase( "test", "test2", "localhost", "<username>", "<password>");
```

But that didn't work out... even when I authenticate myself before doing the copy gives an error... any suggestions anybody how to do this the easiest?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try running the auth command separate. So something like this:

```
mongo "IP"
use test
db.auth("<username>", "<password>")
db.copyDatabase("test", "test2")
```

I think you don't need to put localhost since they are on the same server

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that using "localhost" as the hostname is causing your problem, since "localhost" is not the same for the machine the shell is running on vs. the machine the mongod is running on.  Try using the hostname or ip of the machine the db is running on in the command instead of "localhost".